# Changing row color based on value in a table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to change the color of a row based on the value I have being stored in a table. I have a 1 row 1 column table that contains the average run time of any selected report based off its last 30 runs. I would like to color the row green if the report runs in a given proximity of this value and red otherwise. How would I go about writing the IIF for this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IIF code is going to look something like this to have a criteria to change the color of the fields.

```
IIF(Fields!RunTime.value < AllowableValue,"Green","Red")
```